# ruby method with for loop, unexpected return

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model `MyModel` with a method to return a specific record (see logic below).

```
def self.find_future_rec   #note2
  rec = find(rand(MyModel.count)+1)   #note1
  while rec.nil? | (rec.expdate<Date.today)
    rec = find(rand(MyModel.count)+1)
  end
  return rec
end
```

Every record of `MyModel` class has a variable `expdate` of `Date` class. (I know this is a horrible way to find a record, this is more for my own edification and also some test code.)

1. This method will iterate through several undesirable records before finding an appropriate record, but the record returned is always the one found at `note 1`, the first record queried. Is there some lazy assignment thing going on here?
2. I had to add `self` at `note2` to be able to call the method in a static context. Is this the correct interpretation?

Comment: What makes you think your loop is iterating at all?

Comment: In my Terminal I can see multiple db hits finding undesirable records before stopping after finding a desirable one.

Comment: You'll have to add more information (such as some debugging output of `rec.expdate` before, inside, and after the loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) method never returns `nil` when you give it a single ID to find: if it can't find the record you're asking for, it raises an [`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/RecordNotFound.html) exception. So, `rec` is always non-`nil` and `rec.nil?` is always false. That means that your loop is really like this:

```
while rec.expdate < Date.today
```

If your loop is always returning the `rec` from `#note1` then you're never entering the `while` loop at all and you're always getting a desirable `MyModel` on the first try.

Other points to consider:

1. Sometimes things get deleted so `Model.count + 1` is not necessarily the maximum ID.
2. `find` raises an exception to indicate failure so you need to `rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` rather than check for `nil`.

Answer (score -1):

You are using `|` which is a boolean OR. Try using `or` or `||`.

Adding `self` to make a method a class method ("static" is a decent approximation) is indeed one of the correct ways to approach this.

Comment: `|` is (usually) a bitwise OR but `|` and `||` are the same for booleans.